# making sure a word is a specific length

Tags: java, string

I am new here and I am making a program to allow a person to sign up for something. It takes in the username, compares it with others, and if it is unique, allows it.  When they enter a password however, I don't know how to make sure the word is more than 8 digits.  I need to be able to compare the password with something, and only allow the password if it is more than 8 digits or not.  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some sample code ... attempt

Comment: Call `theString.length()` and make sure it's greater than eight?

Comment: I was trying to upload a picture of it, but it said I needed a higher reputation to do so.  I will copy paste:    //Begin code
        if (name.equals (badName)) {
            usernameConfirmed.setText("username unavailable");
            
        }
        
            else if (!name.equals (badName)) {
                usernameConfirmed.setText("username accepted");
        }
        
        
        if (pass.equals (         )) {
                passwordConfirmed.setText("Password accepted");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should accept the password into a String type. Then compare it with other String using `String.equals(String otherWord)` method and check it's length using `String.length()` method as shown below :-

```
Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
boolean flag=true;
String pwd="";
while(flag) {
pwd=s.nextLine();
if(pwd.length()>8 && pwd.equals("IntendedWord"))
// set flag=false AND then continue your intended action...
else
System.out.println("Please try again");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The method you are looking for is [`String.length()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length()).

Use something like:

```
if (password.length() > 8) {
    // password is long enough
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
 // Previous code gets the value for the field and stores it in String pass

 if ( pass.length() > 8 )
 {
    // it is valid. Hash and save
 }
 else
 {
    // Not valid. Let user know and ask for reentry.
 }

 //etc.
```

You could probably put this and other checking in a validate function and call it before storage.

Let me know if there is anything else you need.

Also, two things to learn about Stack Overflow as a courtesy. Please search for questions similar to yours before posting. And second, give more information when posting so people don't have to guess at what you want/need.

Comment: thank you.  I did search for other questions similar like it said, but didn't really find anything that matched.  I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like

```
if(password.length() > 8)
{
//some logic
}
```

that is, considering that you have your password as a string value.